# Наследование структур в Golang

Tags: golang

Есть 2 структуры

```
type parent struct {
   field1 string
}
type child struct {
   parent
   field2 int
}
```

на выходе получается

```
type child struct {
   parent: parent{
      field1 string
   }
   field2 int
}
```

Как добиться наследования без создания отдельного поля parent
Как сделать чтобы на выходе было так

```
type child {
    field1 string
    field2 int
}
```

Comment: Никак, потому что это уже не наследование, а просто поле с тем же именем что и в родительской структуре.

Comment: `parent: parent{field1 string}` — как это получается на выходе?)

Answer (score 1):

В языке Go нет наследования — есть только композиция (встраивание):

```go
type X struct {
    Value int
    /* ... */
}

func (x X) GetValue() int { return x.Value }

type Y struct {
    X
    /* ... */
}

type Z struct {
    X X
    /* ... */
}
```

При этом обратите внимание, что встраивание в структурах Y и Z разное — в первом случае оно "безымянное", благодаря чему можно вызывать методы X прямо из структуры Y (пример: `Y{}.GetValue()` вернёт 0 как значение `int` по умолчанию), а во втором случае создаётся поле X типа X, из-за чего вызывать методы нельзя (пример: `Z{}.GetValue()` вызовет ошибку при компиляции).

Сделать, чтобы к полю `Value` из структуры `X` можно было обратиться из структуры `Y` или `Z` нельзя (в вашем случае обратиться к полю `field1` из `child`)